# How to modify in real time the video stream from camera on Windows?

Tags: winapi, camera, video-streaming

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344293/how-to-modify-in-real-time-the-video-stream-from-the-iphone-camera). I want to capture and modify video stream from web camera in Windows transparently to all applications using web camera. Whether should it be some kind of driver? Is it possible? Is there API for such tasks? I'm reading about DirectShow filters. Am I on the right direction?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DirectShow to capture the video stream from the camera, modify it, and then pass it on to either a DirectShow source filter (will be seen by some apps as "webcam") or to a kernel driver (will be seen by pretty much every app). If you're new to this do realize this is a lot of work. Depending on what you want to do, consider buying ready made components for your developing environment or even complete applications that can do this (I developed one).

Comment: thanks for your answer! After reading it I searched 'source filter' and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079165/device-driver-to-act-as-a-virtual-web-camera/5079267#5079267. These answers give all information I need to get started